# Regex gives output match of 2 groups haw can i take only number not ""

Tags: python-2.7

My Regex gives output like this : "[('2', '')]" or this : "[('', '2')]"
I want only 2 in both the case.How can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to dimension reduction problem.

Comment: look at this page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html